# Prevent as.character from using exponential notation r

Tags: r, number-formatting, scientific-notation

Is there a way to prevent `as.character` from using exponential notation? For example, I have

```
num <- c(9999999, 10000000)
char <- as.character(num)
char
[1] "9999999" "1e+07"
```

But instead I would like to have `char` be `"9999999" "10000000"`. Thanks!

Comment: This is almost surely a `options(scipen...)` rather than a formatting issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`format` is the function that lets you choose how you want your numbers formatted when converting to character. In this case, something like

```r
format(c(9999999, 10000000), scientific = FALSE, trim = TRUE)
#> [1] "9999999"  "10000000"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `options(scipen = 999)` in the beginning of your `R` script to completely disable scientific notation